# Angular: Generating database information on the fly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, database

The flow of the application that I'm trying to build goes like this: When a page is loaded, a list of jobs will be pulled from 'database/jobs', and displayed. Additionally: for each job, a set of documents that correspond to that job will be pulled. Each of these documents have a number of hours. (Because the total hours for each job is added and then displayed. The total hours for each job needs to be generated each time the page is loaded, and can't be stored in the database).

Currently, the variable 'totalHours' is being resolved as an empty object ({}). I believe (hopefully) my problem is a promise error.

Here are my (mongo) DB schemas for both the jobs, and the entries:

```
var jobSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    expectedHours: Number,
    startDate: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    active: Boolean
});

var entrySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    job: String,
    code: String,
    hours: Number,
    worker: String,
    date: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});
```

And here is the code that I'm working with:

```
$http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'database/jobs'
    }).then(function success(response) {
        $scope.activeJobs = response.data;

        for(var i=0;i<$scope.activeJobs.length;i++){
            $scope.activeJobs[i].totalHours = getTotalHours($scope.activeJobs[i].name);
        }
    }).then(function error(response) {
        $scope.activeJobs = response.statusText;
    });
var getTotalHours = function(name){

        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var count = 0;
        $http.get('database/entries/' + name)
            .success(function(response){
                // ? is this for loop asynchronous?
                // Is resolve() getting called before the loop finishes?
                for(var i=0;i<response.data.length;i++){
                    count += response.data[i].hours;
                }
                deferred.resolve(count);
            }).error(function(response){
               deferred.reject({message:'error?'});
            });
        return deferred.promise;
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you chaining `.then` calls off http? the result from `.then` is not a promise. I think you mean:

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'database/jobs'
}).then(function success(response) {
    $scope.activeJobs = response.data;

    for(var i=0;i<$scope.activeJobs.length;i++){
        $scope.activeJobs[i].totalHours = getTotalHours($scope.activeJobs[i].name);
    }
}, function error(response) {
    $scope.activeJobs = response.statusText;
});
```

That would be my guess. count is not async. If this doesn't work throw a debugger statement in the second .success response and make sure it's being resolved correctly.